# Keyboard navigation: how to go to the next and previous element with arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, keyboard, navigation

I am trying to build a site with keyboard navigation. I want the user to be able to navigate through a menu of five or six pages using the left and right arrows.
No matter on which page is the user, I want him/her to go back/forward in the menu when the left/right arrow is pressed.

Let's say the horizontal menu is built this way :
[Home / Random page / Some page / Another page / And so on]

Apparently it is not working. Here is what I have so far :

```
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       

var pages = ["index.php", "random-page.php", "some-page.php", "another-page.php", "and-so-on.php"];

function leftarrowpressed() {
    location.href = pages[0]-1;
}

function rightarrowpressed() {
    location.href = pages[0]+1;
    }
} 

function KeyCheck(e)
    {
       var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

       switch(KeyID)
       {

 // left arrow key
         case 37:
         leftarrowpressed()    
          break;

//  right arrow key
          case 39:
          rightarrowpressed() 
          break;

       }
    }
```

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pages[0]-1` will evaluate to `"index.php"-1` which is `NaN`. You don't want to subtract 1 from the page URL (you basically cannot subtract from strings) - rather subtract `1` from the index to get the previous page. Also, guard for the bounds:

```
location.href = pages[ Math.max(0, 0 - 1) ];
```

and:

```
location.href = pages[ Math.min(pages.length - 1, 0 + 1) ];
```

I guess you replace the `0` with the index of the current page automatically.

Secondly, you have an extraneous `}` in `rightarrowpressed` it seems.

Comment: This was pretty fast. You are right, I forgot to specify that it gave me a NaN error. Well, it seems to work but only once. If I press the right arrow for the second time, it will not do anything.

Comment: "_I guess you replace the 0 with the index of the current page automatically._" >> How can I do that?

Comment: @Macxim: I assume you have this piece of code on each of the pages, and on `index.php` you have this piece of code with `0`s, on `random-page.php` with `1`s, etc, so that using the left arrow on `random-page.php` you will navigate to `index.php`.

Comment: Actually, I have this piece of code in an external script.js file that I call and the end of the body. Your code is pretty light. I don't know whether _JKing_'s code or yours is better. What do you both think?

Answer (score 1):

okay, I checked out your site and modified/extended my code slightly to try to (almost) achieve what it is I think you want to do. I'm going to leave the other answer unedited because it shows what is probably a better method for doing this... This solution is rather hack-y, and just a way to illustrate the concept.

To see it, go to any of your pages (except the blog page), then open up webkit inspector (my code will only work in WebKit(chrome/safari), although it would be REALLY easy to make it work in any browser) and enter the following into the javascript console:

```
    document.querySelector("footer").setAttribute("style","position:fixed;bottom:0px;width:100%;");
    document.querySelector("header").setAttribute("style","position:fixed;top:0px;width:100%;");

    var pages           =       ["accueil","references","cv","contact","aide","blog"],
    classNames          =       ["accueil","ref","cv","contact","aide","blog"],
    pageUrls            =       ["","references.php","cv.php","contact.php","aide.php","blog/"]
    baseUrl             =       "http://maximelaforet.com/",
    currentPageIndex    =       pageUrls.indexOf(window.location.href.replace(baseUrl,"")),
    pageDivs            =       [1,1,1,1,1,1];

    pageDivs[currentPageIndex] = document.querySelector("div.content");
    pageDivs[currentPageIndex].id = pages[currentPageIndex]+"Page";
    pageDivs[currentPageIndex].setAttribute("style","-webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;position:fixed;top:63px;width:100%;height:"+(window.innerHeight - 270)+"px;overflow:scroll;");

    for (var i=0; i<pageUrls.length;i++)
    {
        if (i!=currentPageIndex)
        {
            var pageGrabber = new XMLHttpRequest();
            pageGrabber.open("GET","http://maximelaforet.com/" + pageUrls[i], false);
            pageGrabber.send(null);

            if (pageGrabber.status==200)
            {
                var temp = document.createElement("div");
                temp.innerHTML = pageGrabber.response;

                if (pages[i]!="blog")
                pageDivs[i] = temp.querySelector("div.content").cloneNode(true);
                else
                pageDivs[i] = temp.querySelector("div#page").cloneNode(true);
            }

            pageDivs[i].id = pages[i]+"Page";
            pageDivs[i].setAttribute("style","-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;position:fixed;top:63px;width:100%;height:"+(window.innerHeight - 270)+"px;overflow:scroll;");
            if (i<currentPageIndex)
            pageDivs[i].style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(-100%,0,0)";
            else
            pageDivs[i].style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(100%,0,0)";

            document.body.appendChild(pageDivs[i]);
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("keyup", KeyCheck, true);
    function KeyCheck(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

        switch(KeyID)
        {
            // left arrow key
            case 37:
            if (currentPageIndex == 0)//we're at the first page, go to the last
            currentPageIndex = pages.length - 1;//-1 to account for first index being "0"
            else//go to the previous page
            pageDivs[currentPageIndex].style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(100%,0,0)";
            pageDivs[currentPageIndex-1].style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0,0,0)";
            document.querySelector("header").classList.remove(classNames[currentPageIndex]);
            document.querySelector("header").classList.add(classNames[currentPageIndex-1]);

            if (classNames[currentPageIndex] == "accueil")
            document.querySelector("li > a[class~='"+classNames[currentPageIndex]+"']").classList.toggle("current_acc");
            else
            document.querySelector("li > a[class~='"+classNames[currentPageIndex]+"']").classList.toggle("current_"+classNames[currentPageIndex]);
            if (classNames[currentPageIndex] == "accueil")
            document.querySelector("li > a[class~='"+classNames[currentPageIndex-1]+"']").classList.toggle("current_acc");
            else
            document.querySelector("li > a[class~='"+classNames[currentPageIndex-1]+"']").classList.toggle("current_"+classNames[currentPageIndex-1]);

            currentPageIndex--;
            break;
            //  right arrow key
            case 39:
            if (currentPageIndex == (pages.length - 1))//if we're at the last page, go to the first
            currentPageIndex = 0;
            else//go to the next page
            pageDivs[currentPageIndex].style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(-100%,0,0)";
            pageDivs[currentPageIndex+1].style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0,0,0)";

            document.querySelector("header").classList.remove(classNames[currentPageIndex]);
            document.querySelector("header").classList.add(classNames[currentPageIndex+1]);

            if (classNames[currentPageIndex] == "accueil")
            document.querySelector("li > a[class~='"+classNames[currentPageIndex]+"']").classList.toggle("current_acc");
            else
            document.querySelector("li > a[class~='"+classNames[currentPageIndex]+"']").classList.toggle("current_"+classNames[currentPageIndex]);
            if (classNames[currentPageIndex] == "accueil")
            document.querySelector("li > a[class~='"+classNames[currentPageIndex+1]+"']").classList.toggle("current_acc");
            else
            document.querySelector("li > a[class~='"+classNames[currentPageIndex+1]+"']").classList.toggle("current_"+classNames[currentPageIndex+1]);

            currentPageIndex++;
            break;
            default:
            var noChange = true;//just so we can ignore the rest if a boring key
        }

    }
```

Keep in mind, though, this is a really hack-y way to do it, but it should point you in the right direction. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Your solution is quite impressive indeed. Thank you! However, I believe that when you checked my site, you saw the result of @pimvbd's solution below. What do you think of it? Does it reduce the amount of HTTP requests and refreshing? Isn't it bad to have that piece of JS on each page? Besides, his solution works in all browsers.

Comment: His solution will perform an HTTP request and refresh the page each time a user switches to a new page, and will require (slightly) different code on each page. The solution I've provided here will perform a few HTTP requests upfront, but never refresh the page, and the same code can be used from each page. The ideal solution would be to combine all of the pages into one, and use a solution similar to this. That way you only need one HTTP request, and never need to refresh. (also, my solution would be REALLY easy to make work in every browser. Like, 5-10 minutes at most to get it working.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems to me you'll need to know which page you're currently on each time for it to work. For this I'd recommend window.localStorage if (and only if) A) all of the pages are served from the same domain, and B) You don't need to support older browsers. If either of those are untrue, this method won't work, and you'll need to do something else like parse the URL string.

I took your code and modified it slightly to show how you might use localStorage. I added some comments, but it should be relatively self-explanatory. Here 'tis:

```
//if current index don't exist, make it
if (!window.localStorage.currentPageIndex)
{
    window.localStorage.currentPageIndex = 0;//frustratingly, it gets stringified anyway - you have to parseInt later
}

//set up vars
var pages        = ["index.php", "random-page.php", "some-page.php", "another-page.php", "and-so-on.php"],
currentPageIndex = parseInt(window.localStorage.currentPageIndex);//as promised

//set event listener on window
window.addEventListener("keyup", KeyCheck);
function KeyCheck(e)
{
    var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

    switch(KeyID)
    {
            // left arrow key
        case 37:
            if (currentPageIndex == 0)//we're at the first page, go to the last
                currentPageIndex = pages.length - 1;//-1 to account for first index being "0"
            else//go to the previous page
                currentPageIndex--;   
            break;
            //  right arrow key
        case 39:
            if (currentPageIndex == (pages.length - 1))//if we're at the last page, go to the first
                currentPageIndex = 0;
            else//go to the next page
                currentPageIndex++;
            break;
        default:
            var noChange = true;//just so we can ignore the rest if a boring key
    }

    if (!noChange)//haha, I love double negatives
    {
        //now dump the new current page index back into localStorage
        window.localStorage.currentPageIndex = currentPageIndex;

        //first, try it in your javascript console to make sure it works (refresh the page!)
        console.log(pages[currentPageIndex],currentPageIndex);
        //then use real urls and uncomment the next line to go to the new current page!
        //location.href = pages[currentPageIndex]
    }
}
```

But - I've gotta ask - do you really want to do it this way? that's a lot of HTTP requests and refreshing the page - are the pages small enough that you could just load them all together at once, and simply only display one at a time? (you could even do a cool sliding or crazy 3d effect between pages - again, assuming you only need to support newer browsers...)

Comment: If you caught this post before my edits, I'm sorry - it does work now. I hadn't tried it as thoroughly as I aught to have... (it's the weekend, which is _almost_ an excuse to be lazy!)

Comment: My purpose is to enhance accessibility, offering an alternative way to navigate through the menu. You can check the result [here](http://maximelaforet.com/). I would also like your opinion on this matter. And review on the rendering. Is it a bad idea to proceed this way?