# Is there a better way to code this in JavaScript and/or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here it is:

```
//Disable KeyboardNavigation
document.getElementById("author").onfocus = function() { 
document.onkeyup = null;
};
document.getElementById("email").onfocus = function() { 
document.onkeyup = null;
};
document.getElementById("url").onfocus = function() {
document.onkeyup = null;
};
document.getElementById("comment").onfocus = function() {
document.onkeyup = null;
};

//Enable KeyboardNavigation
document.getElementById("author").onblur = function() {
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
};
document.getElementById("email").onblur = function() { 
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
};
document.getElementById("url").onblur = function() { 
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
};
document.getElementById("comment").onblur = function() { 
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
};
```

I believe it's definitely possible to write a better code with a loop but I really don't know how to make it work. I tried the following:

```
var formfields= ["author", "email", "url", "comment"];
for (i=1; i<=3; i++){
//Don't really know what to put in here.
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

EDIT : Whole code is below. You should know that [I got some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145461/keyboard-navigation-how-to-go-to-the-next-and-previous-element-with-arrow-keys) to get to this result:

```
document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;       

var pages = [
"http://", 
"http://", 
"http://", 
"http://", 
"http://"];

function leftarrowpressed() {
location.href = pages[ Math.max(0, 0 - 1) ]; 
//The second '0' here changes from 0 to 4, according to the page.
}

function rightarrowpressed() {
location.href = pages[ Math.min(pages.length - 1, 0 + 1) ];
//The second '0' here changes from 0 to 4, according to the page.
}

function KeyCheck(e)
{
   var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

   switch(KeyID)
   {

// left arrow key
     case 37:
     leftarrowpressed();    
      break;

//  right arrow key
      case 39:
      rightarrowpressed(); 
      break; 
   }
}
```

Hope this can help a little more. By the way, thank you everyone. I really don't know which solution to choose.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with that code?

Comment: I have a keyboard navigation on my site. The problem is that when people want to write something in input fields, they can't because specific keys trigger the navigation. That is what I want to avoid. I will put the whole code in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you are doing is trying to prevent keystrokes in an input element from affecting navigation.  What you could do instead is check `event.target` in `KeyCheck` and only perform the action if it was not triggered by an `input` element.

```
function KeyCheck(e) {
    var target = e ? e.target : event.srcElement, //standards vs IE
        tagname = target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if( tagname !== "input" && tagname !== "textarea" && tagname !== "select") {
        //Not from an input, NAVIGATE!
    }
}
```

Comment: Though be aware that a `textarea` isn't an `input` either.

Comment: Good catch.  Added `select` too, just for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

If using jQuery then you can go a more straight-forward way: inside `KeyCheck`, check whether any of the elements is focused, and don't do anything in that case. You won't need any of the above.

```
function KeyCheck(e) {
  if($("#author, #email, #url, #comment").is(":focus")) {
    return;  // ignore if any of these elements has focus
  }

  // ...
}
```

Make sure to bind `KeyCheck` using jQuery too:

```
$("body").on("keyup", KeyCheck);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var formfields= ["author", "email", "url", "comment"];
for (i=0; i<=3; i++){
      var field = document.getElementById(formFields[i]);
      field.onfocus = function() { 
          document.onkeyup = null;
      };
      field.onblur = function() { 
          document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
      };
}

or more proper way would be to use something like this

jQuery.each("author email url comment".split(" "), function(i, name) {
    $('#' + name).focus(function() {
       // do whatever you want to do
    }).blur(function() {
      // do whatever you wnat to do
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Neat and readable:

```
var formfields = ["author", "email", "url", "comment"],
    i, elem,
    blur = function() {   document.onkeyup = KeyCheck; },
    focus = function() {  document.onkeyup = null;     };
for (i=0; i<=3; i++) {
    elem = document.getElementById(formFields[i]);
    elem.onblur = blur;
    elem.onfocus = focus;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

look for the nearest common parent for these elements and add a handler to it. we can use the powers of delegation using the `.on()` as well as method chaining to bind a hander *only to the parent* (in this case, 2 handlers for all, not 8 where 2 per element) to take effect on all 4 elements.

```
var selectors = '#author, #email, #url, #comment';

$('nearest_parent_element').on('focus', selectors, function() {
    document.onkeyup = null;
}).on('blur', selectors, function() {
    document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery way:

```
$("#author, #email, #url, #comment").on({
    focus: function() {
        $(document).on('keyup', null);
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(document).on('keyup', KeyCheck);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how good you are at JavaScript. I would recommend for you to use event delegation: **http://jsfiddle.net/teresko/PkCuZ/3/**

It might look a bit complicated , but the `add_listener()` function would be shared throughout the whole code , so the payload actually looks like this:

```
var handlers = {
    keyout: function(e){  
        var event = e || window.event, 
            target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log( 'leaving ' + target.name ); 
    },
    keyin: function(e){
         var event = e || window.event, 
            target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        console.log( 'entering ' + target.name );
    }
},
container = document.getElementById('container');


add_listener( container, 'blur' , handlers.keyout );
add_listener( container, 'focus' , handlers.keyin );
```

This would work with any number of form elements.

As for the `add_listener()` function , it contains a small fix for blur/focus on IE, and a per-application choice of which method of attaching events to use. It's kinda an universal function which you can just drop in, when you need a common interface for attaching listeners:

```
var add_listener = (function () {
    var fix = {
        'focus':    'focusin',
        'blur':     'focusout'
    };
    if ( window.addEventListener ) {
        return function ( element, type, callback ) {
            element.addEventListener(type, callback, typeof(fix[type]) !== undefined );
        };
    }else{
        return function ( element, type, callback ) {
            type = fix[type] || type;
            element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
        };        
    }
})();
```